# Slide menu like Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

Everyone!

I have already implemented slide menu like fb in one of my app using [MFSideMenuContainerViewController](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu). This gives me slideview from my Appdelegate, as I have integrated this using following:

```
    // allocate side viewcontroller
    SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[[SideMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
  //  leftMenuViewController.view.hidden = NO;
    // allocate menuview to open sideview
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController] leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController rightMenuViewController:nil] ;
 //   [container setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateLeftMenuOpen];
    // assign menu view as a root view for window
    **self.window.rootViewController = container;**
```

Now I want to implement this slideview but not from the RootView.
I have 
`**launch image -> ViewController -> detailViewController**`

So I want my sideview inside detailViewController. How to achieve this using MFSideMenuContainerViewController ?

I have tried with following

```
    // allocate side viewcontroller
    SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[[SideMenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
  //  leftMenuViewController.view.hidden = NO;
    // allocate menuview to open sideview
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:<my ViewController> leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController rightMenuViewController:nil] ;
 //   [container setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateLeftMenuOpen];
    // assign menu view as a root view for window
    **[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];**
```

but this gives the blank white screen with the side menu.

Any help is highly appreciated, as always!
Thanks & Regards

Comment: blank screen means the corresponding view's lay out or any other ?

Comment: Just few sec ago I ran my project and now the blank screen doesn't appear rather my original view is being displayed but I lost my navigationbar

Answer (score 1):

just push it like you push a new view controller from another view controller.

```
[container presentViewController:<my ViewController> animated:yes completion:nil];
```

or

```
[[self navigationController] pushviewcontroller:myController];
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for your reply, but I am sorry I forgot to append the snippet. Check my edited answer now. And let me know if you have any solution

Comment: Though giving you +1 for drawing my attention towards mistake.

Comment: did you try creatign a new UINavigationController and setting your mycontroller as rootviewcontroller to it and pushing this navigtioncontroller.

Comment: you want to push this from detailViewCOntroller.And right now, MFSideMenu displays your detail view controller. on click of something in detailView controller, lets say you are pushing the slideView.Here,in this method, try UINavigationController *nav=[UINavigationcontroller initwithrootviewcontroller:myCOntroller];[detailviewcontroller presentViewController:nav].

Answer (score 0):

Try this helpful for you

```
SplashViewController *splashObj = [[SplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:splashObj];

MainMenuVC *leftViewController = [[MainMenuVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuVC" bundle:nil];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:self.navigationController
                                                          leftMenuViewController:leftViewController
                                                         rightMenuViewController:leftViewController];
container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeNone;
self.window.rootViewController = container;
```

Comment: I can't to like this buddy, as this will apply slideview from the rootview